# How to update to a branch by name?

Tags: mercurial, branch

I've just been doing

```
hg up mybranch
```

Until now, which mostly works fine, but we've got a handful of branches that just have numbers for their name. How is `up` supposed to differentiate between a revision number and a branch name? It doesn't seem to support the `-b` option and I'm not aware of any other method of updating to a branch by name, so what's the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`branch()` revset operator](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) like this:

```
$ hg update "branch(123)"
```

That way you can distinguish between revision numbers, branch names, tags, etc. if you've managed to create an ambiguous name. It's of course discouraged to create such names in the first place, but I'm sure you have figured that out by now :-)

Comment: I'm writing a script, I want to make sure it works in all scenarios :)

Comment: Nice! If your script is in Python, Java, Scale, PHP, or Ruby, then take a look at the corresponding [command server library](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommandServer#Libraries) — that should be easier and make things faster too.

Comment: Turns out this is [wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41864409/65387). `branch()` will not distinguish ambiguities without `literal:`.