# How to update to a branch by name when there's a hash collision?

Tags: mercurial

So my coworker just won the hash lottery. We create a feature branch for every ticket we resolve, following the convention `b#####` where `#####` is the issue number.

The trouble is that when he tried updating to that branch (before it existed) via `hg up branch(b29477)`, it took him to `default` instead of saying that the branch doesn't exist.

It turns out that `branch(b29477)` actually returns the name of branch of the thing inside the parens (instead of forcing Mercurial to evaluate the thing inside the parens as a branch name as I thought!), and there so happened to be a changeset beginning with `b29477` which was on default, so instead of saying the branch didn't exist, it took him to the tip of default!

Now we can work around this problem by choosing a different branch name, but I want to know if there's any way to `hg update <branch_name_and_dont_interpret_this_as_anything_else>`?

---

BTW, `hg log` *also* lies about what it's `--branch` parameter does. It says:

```
-b --branch BRANCH [+]   show changesets within the given named branch
```

But that's not true at all. Go ahead and run it with a hash. e.g.,

```
hg log --branch eea844fb
```

And it will turn up results. If you dig through the docs, you'll discover that it's actually the same as:

```
hg log -r 'branch(eea844fb)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
hg update -r "branch('literal:b29477')"
```

From the Mercurial help page:

> branch(string or set)
>
> All changesets belonging to the given branch or
>   the branches of the given changesets.
>
> If string starts with re:, the remainder of the name is treated as a
>   regular expression. To match a branch that actually starts with re:,
>   use the prefix literal:.

This means that if you use the **literal** prefix, you are specifying a **string**. And a **string** is not a **set**.

As the text says, if you specify a changeset, Mercurial will show:

> the branches of the given changesets

Comment: I doubt you will find issues with bookmarks and tags. Using something like this: `hg update -r "bookmark(mpenBkMrk)"` and `hg update -r "tag(mpenTag)"` is enough.

Comment: Just to be clear, the answer is NO. Command `hg update -r "branch()"` will not accept tags and bookmarks, only branches and sets are accepted.